# Extract links from text file

Tags: regex, bash, awk, sed, grep

I want to build a bash script that extracts the value of the first href attribute. This is a relative link.

So, if take the code snippet below the correct output would be "/prd/amaz/prd151", as this is the text between the first href tag. All the other content in the file need to be removed as I only need the relative link.

```
     <td style="width: 35px;">              
      <a class="productName" href="/prd/amaz/prd151" style="color: #000000;display: inline-block; overflow: hidden">
<font style="font-weight: bold; color: #4f88b2; margin-left: 0px; width: auto" class="product-name">Amaz Prd 151</font></a>                    <br>                    
<font style="font-size: 11px; color: #828585"> Product                   </font>                    <br>
<a href="https://www.myhomedb.com/id=151"><div class="activatedCount withover" title="<div style='color: #0691ca; line-height: 15px; font-size: 11px;'><b>7 Smart Home DB Users<br/></b>actually own this product<br/><br/><b>Click to view their playbooks</b></div>"><span class="icon-size-16 product-category-icon-user-count"></span><span> 7</span></div></a>            </td>
```

I really appreciate your help in this and thanks!

John

Comment: What did you try? if this is a proper `HTML` file, don't parse this with non-syntax aware tools like `grep`, `awk` or `sed`. Use syntax aware parsers

Comment: There is certainly a way to extract all href tags with bash. I have seen examples such as sed `"s/.* href=\"\(.*\)\".*/\1/" output.txt` but this seems to be more trickier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

with `grep` look behind

```
grep -oPm1 '(?<= href=")[^"]+' file
```

note that this is pure textual search.  It's not context aware (whether inside `<a>` tag or not).

[here](https://explainshell.com/explain?cmd=grep%20-oPm1%20%27%28%3F%3C%3Dhref%3D%22%29%5B%5E%22%5D%2B%27%20file) is the explanation of the command